# Performance in running perl program from java spring controller

Tags: java, performance, perl

I am creating a web application where user enters a query and i have a program in perl which tag the words in query. I am writing a spring controller to handle the Web request and then call the perl program from java class. Is this the optimized way. Is there any performance issue or time delay in calling perl program from java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on how you are calling the perl program. When running a perl script, the perl interpreter starts, then compiles the script, then runs it. This means everytime you run program you spawn a new process, read the text file(s) containing the program, interpret them, and then get the results.

This is not optimum.

To optimize the process, write a wrapper in perl for you perl script that runs it continuously in a loop, waiting for input from your java process via a socket, named pipe, or file descriptor. This way, the process does not have to start over and over again. To support greater concurrency, run a pool of these.

Comment: ok. thanks.. if i will change the perl code into java then will it be more faster ?